# C++ library in using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, header

I wrote a test.cpp:

```
      #include <iostream>
      #include <stack>
      #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
      #include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
      #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
      #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

      using namespace std;
      namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
      namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
      namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

     struct calculator
     {
      bool interpret(const string& s);
      void do_neg();
      void do_add();
       void do_sub();
      void do_mul();
        void do_div();
        void do_number(const char* first, const char* last);
          int val() const;
      private:
      stack<int> values_;
      int *pn1_, n2_;
      void pop_1();
      void pop_2();
      };
     ......................
     ....................
```

But when I use g++ test.cpp -o test, there are errors like `boost/lexical_cast.hpp: No such file or directory`, but I have copy all of files in boost (download from boost.org) to the test.cpp folder, how to make g++ know the headers paths? Thanks

I used `g++ test.cpp -o test`

Using `" "` is not possible, I have a lot of header's dependency.

Comment: Make sure you add boost's path to the include for g++, do this with -IPath/to/boost

Comment: gcc test.cpp -IPath/to/boost -o test?

Comment: If you are using `g++` I'd suspect you are on a Unix system. Use your package manager to get boost. It makes life easier.

Comment: Oh， actually I don't have the root....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you modify the include to g++'s command. Reading from the man page (which is your best friend for this sorta stuff):

```
Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for
header files.  Directories named by -I are searched before the
standard system include directories.  If the directory dir is a
standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure
that the default search order for system directories and the
special treatment of system headers are not defeated .  If dir
begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot
prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.
```

For you the command should look like this:

```
g++ -I path/to/boost test.cpp
```